# Drawing cicles on an image view objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, layer

I am trying to draw circles on an image view for an ios application and there will be many circles and I want them to be in the same layer. My circle drawing code is;

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                      radius:radius
                                                  startAngle:0
                                                    endAngle:2.0*M_PI
                                                   clockwise:YES];

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius);
circleLayer.path   = circle.CGPath;
circleLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
```

and I need some thing different than the code below;

```
[imageView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

thanks.

Comment: You should use the `UIImage`'s `drawInRect` method.

Comment: Can you give a sample code? I am little new for Objective C, thanks.

Comment: "and I need some thing different than the code below" What does that even mean?

Comment: Which means  " I need some thing different than the code below"

[imageView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this site: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/drawing-on-uiimages/

```
- (UIImage *)imageByDrawingCircleOnImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    // draw original image into the context
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                image.size.width,
                image.size.height);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, 5, 5);

    // draw circle
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    // make image out of bitmap context
    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I was googling for that for hours.

Comment: I think then it's time to improve your googling skills! This was the 3rd result I got.. Anyway, glad it helped :)